# what problems HTTP persistent connection solves?

Tags: http

I am trying to understand HTTP keep-alive. So what problems it solves. In my understanding it is invented because of TCP 3-way handshake, it tries to reduce the cost of it. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Did you try searching the web and this site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does a "persistent connection" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480329/what-exactly-does-a-persistent-connection-mean)

Comment: In the case of HTTPS connections, it's not just the TCP handshake latency that's amortized over the lifetime of the kept-alive connection, it's also the latency of the TLS handshake (which is much longer than the TCP handshake latency).