# Ruby: Persistent HTTP client not receiving response on second request

Tags: ruby, http, client, persistent, recv

I am trying to create an HTTP client that uses persistent connections.  My Code works when I send my first request and get my first response.  However, when I send a second request, I am unable to get a second response. I am not sure why? I got the same error when I was coding in C.

Here is the code

```
require 'socket'
include Socket::Constants
socket = Socket.new( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 )
sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in( 80, 'www.google.com' )
socket.connect( sockaddr )

# This Works
socket.write( "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" )
results = socket.read

# This Works
socket.write( "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" )
# THIS DOESN'T WORK
results = socket.read
```

I do not want to use built libraries like Net::HTTP.  What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't designed to do your assignment for you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make 2 HTTP requests on the same connection, unless you've told the server that you're expecting to do so.  This is how `HTTP persistent connection` works.  At a minimum, you have to make sure to add this to your request header:

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

Servers have differing support for persistent connections, although it's become common for servers to support basic persistent connections.  Here's an SO question that asks [What exactly does a “persistent connection” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480329/what-exactly-does-a-persistent-connection-mean)

Start there, and you'll find what you need to know to make persistent connections work correctly.  You may have to check the HTTP response headers for an indication that the server will honor your request, or you may have to check that the server didn't simply close the connection when it was finished writing the first response.  On your final request through a persistent connection, you should also specify the header:

```
Connection: close
```

Also check out these resources:

- [IETF HTTP 1.1 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3)
- [W3 HTTP 1.1 section 8: Persistent Connections](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html)
- [Safari Books Online HTTP: The Definitive Guide - Persistent Connections](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s05.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorted!

Comment: @OmarHijazi I'm glad to hear that.  Good luck with your project!